# LINQ: combining join and group by

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, join, group-by

I have a query that combines a join and a group, but I have a problem. The query is like:

```
 var result = from p in Products                         
 join bp in BaseProducts on p.BaseProductId equals bp.Id                    
 group p by p.SomeId into pg                         
 select new ProductPriceMinMax { 
       SomeId = pg.FirstOrDefault().SomeId, 
       CountryCode = pg.FirstOrDefault().CountryCode, 
       MinPrice = pg.Min(m => m.Price), 
       MaxPrice = pg.Max(m => m.Price),
       BaseProductName = bp.Name  <------ can't use bp. 
 };
```

As you see, it joins the `Products` table with the `BaseProducts` table, and groups on an id of the `Product` table. But in the resulting `ProductPriceMinMax`, I also need a property of the `BaseProducts` table: `bp.Name`, but it doesn't know `bp`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Once you've done this

```
group p by p.SomeId into pg
```

you no longer have access to the range variables used in the initial `from`. That is, you can no longer talk about `p` or `bp`, you can only talk about `pg`.

Now, `pg` is a **group** and so contains **more than one** product. All the products in a given `pg` group have the same `SomeId` (since that's what you grouped by), but I don't know if that means they all have the same `BaseProductId`.

To get a base product name, you have to pick a particular product in the `pg` group (As you are doing with `SomeId` and `CountryCode`), and *then* join to `BaseProducts`.

```
var result = from p in Products                         
 group p by p.SomeId into pg                         
 // join *after* group
 join bp in BaseProducts on pg.FirstOrDefault().BaseProductId equals bp.Id         
 select new ProductPriceMinMax { 
       SomeId = pg.FirstOrDefault().SomeId, 
       CountryCode = pg.FirstOrDefault().CountryCode, 
       MinPrice = pg.Min(m => m.Price), 
       MaxPrice = pg.Max(m => m.Price),
       BaseProductName = bp.Name  // now there is a 'bp' in scope
 };
```

That said, this looks pretty unusual and I think you should step back and consider what you are actually trying to retrieve.

Comment: This is better than our solution :) Thanks.

Comment: @AakashM Thanks. But I am fetching a problem with groupVariable.FirstOrDefault().column_name. When I am going to access the IQueryable  variable Result then the error occurred  which heading  is **"entitycommandexecutionexception was unhandled by user code"** with body ***"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."***  I can't understand what is happening.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman sounds to me like you need to [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Be sure to include all the details!

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` always returns null. I made it work with `pg.Key`, which actually makes more sense. I don't understand how `FirstOrDefault` would return any object, when all I'm grouping by is `someId`

Comment: @SZT once youve done a `group`, the thing you end up with (`pg` here) is an `IGrouping`. When you use any of the methods that do enumeration-type-things on an `IGrouping`, what you're iterating on is the members of the group. So `pg.FirstOrDefault()` here is the first (in some arbitrary order) of the `Products` that are in the particular `SomeId` group.

Comment: **// join after group** that's the key, thanks

Answer (score 34):

We did it like this:

```
from p in Products                         
join bp in BaseProducts on p.BaseProductId equals bp.Id                    
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.SomeId) && p.LastPublished >= lastDate                         
group new { p, bp } by new { p.SomeId } into pg    
let firstproductgroup = pg.FirstOrDefault()
let product = firstproductgroup.p
let baseproduct = firstproductgroup.bp
let minprice = pg.Min(m => m.p.Price)
let maxprice = pg.Max(m => m.p.Price)
select new ProductPriceMinMax
{
SomeId = product.SomeId,
BaseProductName = baseproduct.Name,
CountryCode = product.CountryCode,
MinPrice = minprice, 
MaxPrice = maxprice
};
```

EDIT: we used the version of AakashM, because it has better performance

Answer (score 25):

I met the same problem as you.

I push two `tables` `result` into `t1` object and group `t1`.

```
 from p in Products                         
  join bp in BaseProducts on p.BaseProductId equals bp.Id
  select new {
   p,
   bp
  } into t1
 group t1 by t1.p.SomeId into g
 select new ProductPriceMinMax { 
  SomeId = g.FirstOrDefault().p.SomeId, 
  CountryCode = g.FirstOrDefault().p.CountryCode, 
  MinPrice = g.Min(m => m.bp.Price), 
  MaxPrice = g.Max(m => m.bp.Price),
  BaseProductName = g.FirstOrDefault().bp.Name
};
```