# Using Linq to Join,Group By and Count.... facing a trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have two tables, `picture` and `pictureratings` in my db.

```
public partial class picture
{
    public int idpicture { get; set; }
    public int iduser { get; set; }
    public string picTitle { get; set; }
    public string picFilename { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime pictime { get; set; }
    public int nuditylevel { get; set; }
    public int fakeslevel { get; set; }

    // This property will hold the total accumulated/summed 
    // up rating of a picture
    public int totalrating { get; set; }    
}

public partial class pictureratings 
{
    public int idrating { get; set; }
    public int idpictures { get; set; }
    public int iduser { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime iddatetime { get; set; }
    public int iduserrateddby { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; } 
}
```

For every rating a new `pictureratings` row will be created. I want to group `pictureratings` table by the picture id and then count the likes. I want to show those likes in `picture` table in `totalrating` property.

So as per my research till now, I am able to write this code

```
var total = from p in db.picturedetails
            join l in db.picturelikes on p.idpictures equals l.idpictures 
            group l by l.idpictures into g
            select new 
            {
                IdUserPic = g.First().iduser,
                IdPictures = g.First().idpictures,
                totalrating = g.Count()    
            }
```

I am using web api to return query total. So here comes my problem: how to show the `picture` properties like `iduser`, `picTitle`, `picFilename`, `pictime`, `nuditylevel` and `fakeslevel`? Am I doing it right? How should I do it?

Comment: You don't tell us _how_ you're "showing" the properties so how can we say?

Comment: Thanks for asking , i am using web api that shows all the querry total data in a json.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173410/linq-combining-join-and-group-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group an anonymous class. That way you can access both p & l properties.
Looks like this :

```
var total = from p in db.picturedetails
            join l in db.picturelikes on p.idpictures equals l.idpictures 
            group new {p,l} by l.idpictures into g
            select new 
            {
                IdUserPic = g.First().p.iduser,
                IdPictures = g.First().p.nuditylevel,
                totalrating = g.Count()    
            }
```

Comment: I am getting this error after using your technique, ExceptionMessage: "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.",

Comment: Not sure why the first is considered a final when grouping as anonymous but have you tried using FirstOrDefault instead? That being said if you are only intrested in the number of joined records i would go for Tim's group join solution, a little less flexible but it looks cleaner imho :)

Comment: FirstOrDefault will just give one picture details.

Answer (score 1):

I think a [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397905.aspx) is what you're looking for:

```
var total = from p in db.picturedetails
            join l in db.picturelikes on p.idpicture equals l.idpictures into pl
            select new
            {
                Picture = p,
                AverageRating = pl.Any()
                                    ? pl.Average(l => l.rating)
                                    : (double?)null,
                RatingsCount = pl.Count(),
                TotalRating = pl.Sum(l => (float?)l.likenumber) ?? 0
            };
```

If a picture has no likes, this will give a `0` total and `null` average for that picture.

Comment: it works, could you please tell me how to average all the rattings? like its just giving me count, i need total average of those ratings? For average i need sum.. how to find the sum of alll the pictures with same picture id?

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm added code to calculate average using LINQ's [`Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx).

Comment: I am getting this error while using average or sum "The cast to value type 'Single' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.", This is my code  totalrating = (pl.Sum(l =>l.likenumber))

Comment: Could be a bug due to how the translated SQL handles an empty list. Try `TotalRating = pl.Select(l => l.rating).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()`

Comment: Or `totalrating = (pl.Sum(l => (float?)l.likenumber))`

Comment: TotalRating = pl.Select(l => l.rating).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() gives "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.Inner exption: "Unknown column 'Project1.idpictures' in 'where clause'"

Comment: totalrating = (pl.Sum(l => (float?)l.likenumber))  gives Cannot implicitly convert type 'float?' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm `totalrating = pl.Sum(l => (float?)l.likenumber).GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Single GetValueOrDefault()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.",

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38041/discussion-between-tim-s-and-hmmmmmmmmmm)