# Error in linq query when using average

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have two tables, `picture` and `pictureratings` in my database.

```
public partial class picture
{
    public int idpicture { get; set; }
    public int iduser { get; set; }
    public string picTitle { get; set; }
    public string picFilename { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime pictime { get; set; }
    public int nuditylevel { get; set; }
    public int fakeslevel { get; set; }

    // This property will hold the total accumulated/summed 
    // up rating of a picture
    public int totalrating { get; set; }    
}

public partial class pictureratings 
{
    public int idrating { get; set; }
    public int idpictures { get; set; }
    public int iduser { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime iddatetime { get; set; }
    public int iduserrateddby { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; } 
}
```

For every rating a new `pictureratings` row will be created. I want to group `pictureratings` table by the picture id and then count the likes. I want to show those likes in `picture` table in `totalrating` property.

So as per my now I am able to write the following code

```
 var combo = from p in db.picturedetails
                    join l in db.picturelikes on p.idpictures equals l.idpictures into pl
                    select new LikesandPictureDetails
                    {
                             IdUserPic = p.iduser,
                           IdPicturess =p.idpictures,
                           Likes = p.likes,
                           NudityLevel = p.nuditylevel,
                           PicTitle = p.picTitle,
                           PicTime = p.pictime,
                           picFilename=p.picFilename,
                           Count=pl.Count(),
                           totalrating = pl.Average(c => c.likenumber) // This line is causing error
                    };
```

I am using web api to return query total. I am showing  `picture` properties like `iduser`, `picTitle`, `picFilename`, `pictime`, `nuditylevel` and `fakeslevel`.

As per now  every thing runs smooth, but when I add totalrating = pl.Average(c => c.likenumber) , I get an exception saying

> The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

How to remove the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Linq to Join,Group By and Count.... facing a trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007164/using-linq-to-join-group-by-and-count-facing-a-trouble)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the problem is that pl has no records, try

replace

```
totalrating = pl.Average(c => c.likenumber) // This line is causing error
```

with

```
totalrating = pl.DefaulIfEmpty(0).Average(c => c.likenumber)
```

Answer (score 2):

db.picturelikes.likenumber seems to be nullable? Can't find the property defined in your code though.
Anyways you can select all entries which are not null by putting

```
pl.Where(a=>a.likenumber != DBNull.Value /* or null whatever this is... */).Average...
```

If it is a nullable property:

```
pl.Where(a=>a.likenumber.HasValue).Average(a=>a.likenumber.Value)
```

:edit
I think .average returns a null-able decimal in this case. To assign it to your field, simply put

```
totalrating = pl.Average(c => c.likenumber)
```

Totalrating seems to be an int, eigther you'll loose some information by casting it down to an int, or you change the type to double...

Comment: Both doesnt work. Hasvalue option is not apeparing in intellisense.

Comment: What kind of type is likenumber?

Comment: Dbnull gives Errr : Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: Ah, .Average returns nullable decimal. Simply put .Value, pl.Average(c => c.likenumber).Value

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be that your DB has a column that can contain `null` values, yet your object has a non-nullable `double` type.

Does the query run if you select an anonymous type, instead of a concrete one?

ie. change this

```
select new LikesandPictureDetails
```

to

```
select new
```

If so, then you should change the type of a value in your target object to be nullable.