# LINQ: Join 5 or 6 tables and group by one then count groupby data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Tables are : From Child level to Parent Level:

> TRAINING_TEACHER >TEACHER >INSTITUTE >SUBDISTRICT >DISTRICT
>   ZONE(DIVISION)

I need to show institute name and it's male and female teacher participated in training group by SUBDISTRICT. My View model is :

```
 public class TRAINING_STATUS_VIEW_MODEL
  {
    public int countMale { get; set; }
    public int countFemale { get; set; }
    public ZONE ZONE_VIEW_MODEL { get; set; }
    public DISTRICT DISTRICT_VIEW_MODEL { get; set; }
    public SUBDISTRICTUPAZILA_VIEW_MODEL { get; set; }
    public INSTITUTE INSTITUTE_VIEW_MODEL { get; set; }
  }
```

Where countMale, countFemale are numbers of teacher from each institute in TRAINING_TEACHER table according to gender. There is a gender column in TEACHER table. 
Now here is the query I can not performing group by as institute and count.

```
var trainingStatusReport = 
from trainingTeacher in db.TRAINING_TEACHER 
join teacher in db.TEACHERs on trainingTeacher.TEACHER_NO equals teacher.TABLE_ID 
join institute in db.INSTITUTEs on teacher.INS_ID equals institute.INS_ID
join subDistrict in db.subDistricts on institute.LOC_ID equals (decimal)subDistrict.LOC_ID
join district in db.DISTRICTs on (decimal)subDistrict.DCODE equals (decimal)district.DCODE
join zone  in db.ZONEs on  district.ZC equals  zone.ZC   
select new TRAINING_STATUS_VIEW_MODEL { 
..........
.......... I can't go here
} ;
```

I have tried with group institute by institute.ins_id but couldn't code in select section.

Comment: Do you need the grouping of teachers by institute alone, or a grouping of teachers by zone?

Comment: count in Institute and group by subDistrict.

Comment: Can you show some test data and desired result?

Comment: I need to draw it now. Another better understanding way is training_teacher is under techer, teacher is under instiute , institute is under subdistrict, subdistrict is under distrcit,distrcit is under zone. The thing I can not is group by subdistrcit and count as institute male and female teacher.

Comment: All these joins are not necessary. Declare the proper navigation properties and all joins go away.

Comment: Are you able to add the navigation properties? The group by will be much simpler to write out. i.e. you can then go `group trainingTeacher by trainingTeacher.Teacher.Institute into instituteGroup` and use the aggregations there

Comment: @Balah your suggestion worked :) But fall in  truble when wanted to join with the grouped variabe by firstordefault().column_name

Comment: For that you will need the 'let' statement, not a join. I will post an answer just now

Comment: I have solved my answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173410/linq-combining-join-and-group-by/9173994#comment58058289_9173994 both two answer from @AakashM and @ L-Three was helpful

Answer (score 0):

To use a group by with further joins is possible, but can get inefficient. A better alternative to joins is to

1. use navigation properties
2. use the `let` statement to simplify any other complex logic.

Here is an example of how to combine the two. Does this solve the problem?

```
var trainingStatusReport =
    from trainingTeacher in db.TRAINING_TEACHER
    group trainingTeacher by trainingTeacher.Teacher.Institute into instituteGroup
    let institute = instituteGroup.Select(t => t.Teacher.Institute).FirstOrDefault()
    select new TRAINING_STATUS_VIEW_MODEL
    {
        countMale = instituteGroup.Count(t => t.Teacher.Gender == Male),
        countFemail = instituteGroup.Count(t => t.Teacher.Gender == Femail),
        ZONE = institute.SubDistrict.District.Zone,
        DISTRICT = institute.SubDistrict.District,
        SUBDISTRICT = institute.SubDistrict,
        INSTITUTE = institute
    };
```