# How to do a Group by while joining three tables in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to do a groupby while joining three tables in LINQ. Below is my code. Any suggestions on how to do this will be a great help.

```
var result = (from cm in DB.BRAND_NAME_MAP_COMMENTs
          join R in DB.BRAND_NAME_MAP_MASTERs on cm.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID equals R.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID
          join K in DB.V_BRANDNAME_INGREDIENT_MAPs on R.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID equals K.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID
          orderby cm.UPDATED_TS descending
          group K.PFC_DESC by K.RAND_NAME_MAP_ID into L  //this where the problem is                          
          select new WorkflowComment
          {
              NAMEVersion   = L.PFC_DESC + "-" + K.PFC_VERSION,
              BRAND_NAME    = R.BRAND_NAME,
              HC_BRAND_NAME = R.HC_BRAND_NAME,
              NAME          = K.PFC_DESC,
              //VERSION     = K.PFC_VERSION,
              COMMENTS      = cm.COMMENTS.Replace("\n", "<br />"),
              UPDATED_BY    = cm.UPDATED_BY,
              UPDATED_TS    = cm.UPDATED_TS
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: I still don't understand people's obsession with writing stuff like this instead of just using the database engine to write complex queries...it's like having an axe to cut down a tree, but instead of using it, you use a dull knife.

Comment: Well, if they don't have the knowledge, taking the time to understand it, might be to much. If they were taught only a code first approach f.x. They won't have a good time. 

That being said, there is a level of professionalism to know all aspects of the tool you are using. Thus learning the strength and weaknesses of a such a powerful tool as the Linq query system, is quite a valid practice. 

I don't actually understand people who question others for their pursuit of knowledge. 

Unfortunately I don't have the skill to solve this issue for the OP. I wish I did.

Comment: @RyanWilson Well I don't wanna change the entire logic to use an axe. This is just a small code snippet from a huge dependent code that is used in some scenario.

Comment: @MortenBork Not questioning the OP's pursuit of knowledge, just the reasoning behind why not to just write it in SQL instead. Which they just answered.

Comment: It would help with an expected result set. And what precisely isn't working. Are you getting an exception? is the result different than what you expect? (ie. what do you expect?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checking, if you read the following link: 
[LINQ: combining join and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173410/linq-combining-join-and-group-by)

I feel it's the same problem that you are facing.