# Add a Lambda in a LINQ query to replace a line in a foreach

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a situation where I have to match up multiple customers numbers from one system with a single customer number in another system.
So for instance customer number 225, 228 and 223 in system A will all map to customer number 110022 in system B.
Easy enough, I have a matrix setup to do that.

I pull the matrix data in like this:

```
 var dt_th_matrix = (from m in aDb.Matrix_Datatrac_TopHat select m).ToArray();
```

So the records would be something like:

customerA: 3  CustomerB: 1001

CustomerA: 4  CustomerB: 1001

CustomerA: 5  Customer: 1002

Then I do a big data pull and step through all the items.  For each of the items I go grab the matching customer number from the matrix like this:

```
foreach (var dt_stop in mainPull)
        {
            int? th_customerId = (from d in dt_th_matrix 
                                  where d.datatrac_customer_no == dt_stop.Customer_No.ToString() 
                                  select d.tophat_customer_detail_Id).First();
```

What I would rather do is to just embed the code to grab the customer numbrer from the matrix directly in my datapull -- the part "Query goes here somehow"  will be some type of Lambda I assume.  Any help?

I have tried something like this:

```
  th_customerId = (dt_th_matrix.First().tophat_customer_detail_Id.Equals c.Customer_No)
```

But that is not it (obviously)

```
var mainPull = (from c in cDb.DistributionStopInformations
                        join rh in cDb.DistributionRouteHeaders on c.Route_Code equals rh.Route_Code
                        where c.Company_No == 1 &&
                       (accountNumbers.Contains(c.Customer_No)) &&
                         (brancheSearchList.Contains(c.Branch_Id) && brancheSearchList.Contains(rh.Branch_Id)) &&
                        c.Shipment_Type == "D" &&
                       (c.Datetime_Created > dateToSearch || c.Datetime_Updated > dateToSearch) &&
                       rh.Company_No == 1 &&
                       ((rh.Route_Date == routeDateToSearch && c.Route_Date == routeDateToSearch) ||
                       (rh.Route_Date == routeDateToSearch.AddDays(1) && c.Route_Date == routeDateToSearch.AddDays(1)))
                        orderby c.Unique_Id_No
                        select new
                        {
                            c.Datetime_Updated,
                            th_customerId = ("Query goes here somehow")
                            c.Datetime_Created,
                            c.Unique_Id_No,
                            c.Original_Unique_Id_No,
                            c.Unique_Id_Of_New_Stop,
                            c.Branch_Id,
                            c.Route_Date,
                            c.Route_Code,
                            c.Sequence_Code,
                            c.Customer_No,
                            c.Customer_Reference,
                            c.Shipment_Type,
                            c.Stop_Name,
                            c.Stop_Address,
                            c.Stop_City,
                            c.Stop_State,
                            c.Stop_Zip_Postal_Code,
                            c.Stop_Phone_No,
                            c.Stop_Arrival_Time,
                            c.Stop_Departure_Time,
                            c.Address_Point,
                            c.Stop_Special_Instruction1,
                            c.Stop_Special_Instruction2,
                            c.Stop_Expected_Pieces,
                            c.Stop_Expected_Weight,
                            c.Stop_Signature,
                            c.Actual_Arrival_Time,
                            c.Actual_Depart_Time,
                            c.Actual_Service_Date,
                            c.Stop_Actual_Pieces,
                            c.Stop_Exception_Code,
                            c.Created_By,
                            rh_Route_Date = rh.Route_Date,
                            routeHeaderRouteCode = rh.Route_Code,
                            rh.Actual_Driver,
                            rh.Assigned_Driver,
                            rh_routeDate = rh.Route_Date

                        }).ToArray();
```

I will try and clarify the above.

What I need is for the Linq query to say :
For each record that I pull I will goto the Array named dt_th_matrix and get the record that matches for this line and use it.

The data in the matrix looks exactly like this:

Record 1: datatrac_customer_no: 227, tophat_customer_detail_Id 1

Record 2: datatrac_customer_no: 228, tophat_customer_detail_Id: 1

Record 3: datatrac_customer_no: 910, tophat_customer_detail_Id: 5

Then for the first record pulled in the mainPull the field c.customer_no == 228 so I need the query in the select new statement to replace th_customerId with 1 (from Record 2 in the Matrix.

Then say the next record pulled in the mainPull the field c.customer_no = 910 the th_customerId would be 5.

That is what the first line of my foreach statement is currently doing. I want to move that logic to inside my LINQ query.

Comment: It's easier for me to follow with some sample data, so I'm not quite sure on the syntax for you, but I think you want a group by clause on the id at first, and then join off of that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9173410/1462295

Comment: I added clarification and more data.  I read over the group by link you provided and that does not look like it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, using a dictionary with a key of datatrac_customer_no and a value of tophat_customer_detail_Id would be a good idea here:

```
var dt_th_matrix = (from m in aDb.Matrix_Datatrac_TopHat select m).ToDictionary(m=>m.datatrac_customer_no,m=>m.tophat_customer_detail_Id);
```

With this you should be able to replace your "Query goes here somehow" with

```
dt_th_matrix[c.Customer_No]
```

Using LINQ would be possible as well, but I don't think it's worth the performance overhead and reduction in readibility.

If you still want to use LINQ for this with your original matrix, this should work as your query:

```
dt_th_matrix.Single(m => m.datatrac_customer_no == c.Customer_No).tophat_customer_detail_Id
```

Both expressions will throw an exception if the key is not found or exists multiple times - but if I understand your structure correctly this should not be possible. Otherwise you need to check for this.

Comment: Thank you -- I never thought about using a dictionary, good idea.