# Trouble with linq query syntax group by expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating an timesheet app, I would like to display following:

For each employee into a grid:

Id, Name, TaskName, SunHours, MondayHours... and so on FridayHours

```
Employee_Table
empid
name

Timesheet
id
empid
taskid
sat
sun
mon
tues
wed
thurs
fri
sat

Task
taskid
taskname
```

[image: Timesheet table]

I am struggling to create the object from a linq query as I cannot access the timesheet specific data i.e sun, mon, tue values. Here is what I have done:

```
   var result = (from e in db.Employees
                          join t in db.TimeSheets on e.Id equals t.EmployeeId
                          group e by t.TaskId into g
                          orderby g.Key
                          select new
                          {
                              empid = g.Key,
                              name = g.Select(e => e.Name),
                              sat = g.Select(s => s.Saturday), // cannot access this info
                              sun = g.Select(s => s.Sunday),
                              mon = g.Select(s => s.Monday),
                              tue = g.Select(s => s.Tuesday),
                              wed = g.Select(s => s.Wednesday),
                              thurs = g.Select(s => s.Thursday),
                              fri = g.Select(s => s.Friday),
                          });
```

Update:

So, I have ended up with this - it seems to represent what I am after.

```
var res = (from e in db.Employees
               join t in db.TimeSheets on e.Id equals t.EmployeeId

               group t by new { t.EmployeeId } into g
               select new
               {
                   id = g.Key.EmployeeId,
                   data = g
                   });
```

Comment: This type of question has been asked more often. Look for LINQ + pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173410/linq-combining-join-and-group-by), grouping by 'e' only makes the 't' objects out of scope.

You can join to the employee table after grouping the Timesheet objects. Looks like you may also need `.Sum(s => s.mon)` instead of `.Select(s => s.mon)`

Edit: .Sum() not .Max()