# How do I correctly use LINQ groupby for two tables joined via an intermediate table?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have three tables.

1. Interviews
2. Interviewers
3. InterviewSchedule.

An *interviewer* can be scheduled for multiple *interviews*

An *interview* can have multiple *interviewers*.

So,

- *InterviewSchedule* table has columns `interviewid`, `interviewerid`. (Many to many relationship)
- *Interviewtable* has columns - `InterviewId`, `InterviewLocation`,  `InterviewSubject`.
- *Interviewer* table has columns - `InterviewerId`, `InterviewerName`, `InterviewerTitle`.

Now, I want to generate a report of *interviews* with the *interviewer details*.
I created a `dataobject` as `InterviewId`, `InterviewLocation`, `InterviewSubject`, `List<Interviewer>`;

I am trying to make one *LINQ* query to get my output. I use *entityframework* and already have the context created.

I am kind of new to *LINQ*, but I see this should be possible and I saw multipleposts from people `groupby`, using Id.

I think my problem is I want to select multiple fields from both the tables via the intermediate table.

```
var output = (from i in Interview 
              join ia in InterviewSchedule on i.interviewid equals ia.interviewid 
              join iw in Interviewers on ia.interviewerid equals iw.interviewerid) 
              group i by i.interviewid into g 
              select new {i, interviewers = new {interviewername, interviewertitle} };
```

I am lost at this point. Is this not the right approach? Do I have to make a 'for' loop to add all the interviewers to the list, one by one?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-1-the-basics/)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this

```cs
            var output = (from i in Interview
                          group i by i.InterviewId into g
                          join ia in InterviewSchedule on g.Key equals ia.InterviewId
                          join iw in Interviewers on g.Key equals iw.InterviewerId
                          select new { g.Key, interviewers = iw }).ToList();
```

see [LINQ: combining join and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173410/linq-combining-join-and-group-by)