# Problem with converting raw SQL to Entity Framework, order by, count

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a trouble with converting this SQL query to Entity Framework:

```
SELECT Products.Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM OrdersProducts 
JOIN Products on OrdersProducts.ProductId = Products.Id 
GROUP BY Products.Id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Tried hard but with no results. I don't have any idea how to make it work.

Comment: The answer is provided in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9173783/7855321)

Comment: You should list your models and their relationships and what data you need to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your entity model relations allows it, you could try something like that :

```
dbcontext.Products
.Include(orders=> orders.OrderProducts)
.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Count = x.OrderProducts.Count })
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
.ToList();
```

I think the SQL generated by EF could be near of your query...

Comment: It works good, but how can I order and group without displaying `Count`? Now I have to display only `Name`, because of my model doesn't have `Count` field it shows an error, Cannot convert to anonymous type.

Comment: try to add your custom Select after OrderBy. for example `.Select(x=>x.Name)`.